# How do I find a Google user's ID without the user logging in, in advance?

Tags: google-oauth, google-identity

I don't where to ask questions at https://developers.google.com/identity/ so I am asking here.

I've been tinkering with using Google as an [authentication provider](https://github.com/dghubble/gologin/). I've setup my app with:

- GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
- GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

Though now I'm interested in [assigning admin permissions in my test code](https://github.com/kaihendry/internal-google-login/blob/master/main.go#L174) to other Google users identified by email address. How do I know what the ID is of say **example@gmail.com** so I can add that person to an admin list?

I don't want the user to login first to figure out their 21 digit ID!

Comment: So you want to know what a user's Google ID is based on their email before they log into your program. Is that right?

Comment: Correct! Is that possible?

Comment: I would hope not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to search on a google email address and get any information about that user including their Google user id.  This would have a large number of security ramifications in my opinion.

You need to have the user login then you can use the user info endpoint to get back the information you need.